# mXparser's iff() conditional does not support equality test

Tags: c#, math, mxparser

I'm using the Java/.NET symbolic math library `mXparser` (5.0.2) to support user-provided math expressions in my app.

### Problem

I found that [the conditional clause](https://mathparser.org/mxparser-tutorial/using-built-in-functions/) `iff` does not support equality test, e.g.,

```cs
var f = new Function("f(x1, x2) = x1 + x2");
var g = new Function("g(x1, x2) = x1 * x2");
var k = new Function("k(x1, x2) = x1 - x2");
      
var h = new Function("h(x1, x2) = iff(x1 > x2, f(x1, x2); x1 < x2, g(x1, x2)); x1 == x2, k(x1, x2))", f, g, k);

e = new Expression("h(2, 1)", h);
mXparser.consolePrintln($"Res: {e.getExpressionString()} = {e.calculate()}");

e = new Expression("h(1, 2)", h);
mXparser.consolePrintln($"Res: {e.getExpressionString()} = {e.calculate()}");

e = new Expression("h(2, 2)", h);
mXparser.consolePrintln($"Res: {e.getExpressionString()} = {e.calculate()}");
```

This gives

```
[mXparser-v.5.0.2 bin NET6_0] Res: h(2, 1) = NaN
[mXparser-v.5.0.2 bin NET6_0] Res: h(1, 2) = NaN
[mXparser-v.5.0.2 bin NET6_0] Res: h(2, 2) = NaN
```

### Workaround

I could turn to `if` clause to do something like

```cs
var h = new Function("h(x1, x2) = if(x1 == x2, k(x1, x2))", k);
```

But it's still annoying to use separate statements instead of an integrated expression.

### Question

Am I missing something or is this by design?

Comment: Hi, can you share the result of e.getErrorMessage() string?

Comment: I run your code, result seems to be ok
[mXparser-v.5.0.2 bin NET6_0] Res: h(2, 1) = 3
[mXparser-v.5.0.2 bin NET6_0] Res: h(1, 2) = 2
[mXparser-v.5.0.2 bin NET6_0] Res: h(2, 2) = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work properly when I run below code:

```
Expression e;

var f = new Function("f(x1, x2) = x1 + x2");
var g = new Function("g(x1, x2) = x1 * x2");
var k = new Function("k(x1, x2) = x1 - x2");

var h = new Function("h(x1, x2) = iff(x1 > x2, f(x1, x2); x1 < x2, g(x1, x2); x1 == x2, k(x1, x2))", f, g, k);

e = new Expression("h(2, 1)", h);
mXparser.consolePrintln($"Res: {e.getExpressionString()} = {e.calculate()}");

e = new Expression("h(1, 2)", h);
mXparser.consolePrintln($"Res: {e.getExpressionString()} = {e.calculate()}");

e = new Expression("h(2, 2)", h);
mXparser.consolePrintln($"Res: {e.getExpressionString()} = {e.calculate()}");
```

Code result:

```
[mXparser-v.5.0.2 bin NET6_0] Res: h(2, 1) = 3
[mXparser-v.5.0.2 bin NET6_0] Res: h(1, 2) = 2
[mXparser-v.5.0.2 bin NET6_0] Res: h(2, 2) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks. I found my problem: In my actual code, I spell the `iff` expression wrong where I closed the parentheses too early before the equality test happens. But this was so confusing because not much error log showed up in the console.

Comment: I updated my question to reflect that bug.